# How to grok (and modify) this Perl statement

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl.

How do I interpret this Perl statement?:

```
my( $foo, $bar ) = split /\s+/, $foobar, 2;
```

I know that local variables are being simultaneously assigned by the split function, but I don't understand what the integer 2 is for - I'm guessing the func will return an array with two elements?.

Can a Perl monger explain the statement above to me (ELI5)

Also, on occasion, the string being split does not contain the expected tokens, resulting in either foo or bar being uninitialized and thus causing a warning when an attempt is made to use them further on in the code.

How do I initialize $foo and $bar to sensible values (null strings) in case the split "fails" to return two strings?

Comment: You should know that the split pattern `/\s+/` does not strip leading whitespace, and in many cases what you want is actually `' '`, which is the default pattern, and does the same thing, except it also strips leading whitespace (it emulates awk's behaviour).

Comment: Wait, wait, wait, wait... let me get this right. You couldn't be bothered to Google "[perldoc split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)"??????? Are you SERIOUS? How ON EARTH did you get 2,800 experience points? HOW?

Comment: @PP Points aren't everything. Look at the badges.  He has Popular Question x 71.  You have Popular Question x 7.  Try and ask a few more popular questions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` function takes three arguments:

1. A regex that matches separators, or the special value `" "` (a string consisting of a single space), which trims the string, then splits at whitespace like `/\s+/`.
2. A string that shall be split.
3. A maximum number of resulting fragments. Sometimes this is an optimization when you aren't interested in all fields, and sometimes you don't want to split at each separator, as is the case here.

So your `split` expression will return at most two fields, but not neccessarily exactly two. To give your variables default values, either assign default values before the `split`, or check if they are `undef` after the `split`, and give the default:

```
my ($foo, $bar) = ('', '');
($foo, $bar) = split ...;
```

or combined

```
(my ($foo, $bar) = ('', '')) = split ...
```

or

```
my ($foo, $bar) = split ...;
$_ //= '' for $foo, $bar;
```

The `//=` operator assigns the value on the RHS if the LHS is `undef`. The `for` loop is just a way to shorten the code.

You may also want to carry on with a piece of code only when exactly two fields were produced:

```
if ( 2 == (my ($foo, $bar) = split ...) ) {
  say "foo = $foo";
  say "bar = $bar";
} else {
  warn "could not split!";
}
```

List assignment in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements assigned.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. Perl is completely different from other languages I have used ;).  `$_//=` <- This right here, is why I'm scared of Perl!

Comment: Cmon, the operators are listed in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). That's a fun read! :)

Answer (score 1):

The 2 is the maximum number of components returned by split.

Thus, the regexp `/\s+/` splits `$foobar` on clumps of whitespace, but will only split once, to make two components.  If there is no whitespace, then $bar will be undefined.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

In addition to amon's method, Perl has a `defined(x)` function that returns true or false depending on whether its argument `x` is defined or undefined, and this can be used in an `if` statement to correct cases where something is undefined.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

"If LIMIT is specified and positive, it represents the maximum number of fields into which the EXPR may be split;"

For example:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

my $foobar = "A B C D";
my( $foo, $bar ) = split /\s+/, $foobar, 2;

print "\nfoo=$foo";
print "\nbar=$bar";
print "\n";
```

output:

```
foo=A
bar=B C D
```